# Why typecasting increases matrix's row/column size?

Tags: matlab, matrix, typecast-operator

when I write this code (just for testing. This thing occurs other type casting too):

```
y_quan=typecast(y_quan,'int8');
```

dimension of y_quan changes drastically . Before typecasting it was a double type 1X15310 matrix. But after this typecasting operation it became int8 type 1X122480 matrix. 
why this is happening ? anyone please explain.
How can I prevent this?

Comment: did you read [the documentation](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/typecast.html)? "typecast is different from the MATLAB® cast function in that it does not alter the input data. typecast always returns the same number of bytes in the output Y as were in the input X"

Comment: Matlab help http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/typecast.html here explains it quite well, by default, it assumes that your y_quan is an array of double which happens to 64 bits, when you typecast it to 8 bit Int, it needs extra length to represent the number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can I prevent this?

Don't use `typecast`, it's obviously the wrong function.

That's the behaviour you're explicitely asking for. From the [Matlab documentation, which is the obvious place that someone should look when researching functionality](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/typecast.html):

> `typecast` is different from the MATLAB® `cast` function in that it does not alter the input data. `typecast` always returns the same number of bytes in the output Y as were in the input X. For example, casting the 16-bit integer 1000 to uint8 with typecast returns the full 16 bits in two 8-bit segments (3 and 232) thus keeping its original value (3*256 + 232 = 1000). The cast function, on the other hand, truncates the input value to 255.

Which means that your `double` matrix, which has 64 bit per element, has 15310 * 8 Byte storage. Now, typecasting that to 8-bit (==1Byte) values, ithe result has 8 times as many elements.